# cannot configure tomcat logging.properties

Tags: tomcat, servlets, logging

I'm going to use standard Tomcat logging without log4j for simplicity. In logging.properties I've appended in this file new AsyncFileHandler item.
In "handlers = " - 5Report.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, also 3 lines of handler specific properties:

```
5Report.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
5Report.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5Report.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = Report.
```

and 2 lines of facility specific properties:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/Report].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/Report].handlers = 5Report.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
but output processes to "localhost" log, not to Report.....log
```

In servlet I use `getServletConfig().getServletContext().log(...)`

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Phrase "but output processes to "localhost" log, not to Report.....log" fit in code. I need output to separate file